# SQL Aggregations on groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a relative new comer to SQL and am stuck.  I have written a query that returns a list of transactions made by individuals, each of whom possesses  an unique ID number-PARENTACCOUNT.  I want to divide these individuals into groups based on the number of transactions they have made (e.g., 0 transactions, 1-2 transactions, 3-4 transactions, etc.).  Then I want to have a count of the individuals  and calculate the average transaction amount for each group.  Here is the query that yields the list of transactions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT st.BALANCECHANGE
    ,st.PARENTACCOUNT
    ,s.ID
    ,st.SEQUENCENUMBER
    ,st.POSTDATE
FROM dbo.ACCOUNT AS a
    JOIN dbo.SAVINGSTRANSACTION AS st
        ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = st.PARENTACCOUNT
    JOIN dbo.CARD AS c
        ON st.PARENTACCOUNT = c.PARENTACCOUNT
            AND a.ProcessDate = st.ProcessDate
    JOIN dbo.SAVINGS AS s
        ON st.PARENTACCOUNT = s.PARENTACCOUNT
            AND s.ID = st.PARENTID
            AND s.ProcessDate = a.ProcessDate
            AND s.PARENTACCOUNT = a.ACCOUNTNUMBER
WHERE a.ProcessDate >= (SELECT MAX(ACCOUNT.ProcessDate) FROM ACCOUNT)
    AND a.TYPE <= 2
    AND s.CLOSEDATE IS NULL
    AND s.SHARECODE = 1
    AND (c.TYPE = 15 OR c.TYPE = 16)
    AND c.EXPIRATIONDATE > GETDATE()
    AND c.STATUS = 1
    AND st.SOURCECODE = 'O'
    AND st.VOIDCODE = 0
    AND st.POSTDATE >= (DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)))
    AND st.POSTDATE <=(DATEADD(D,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)))
```

So I want to group by the transaction groups and perform aggregate commands on the groups. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server?  Using table aliases will greatly increase the readability of your code.  Are the fields in your `SELECT` list the ones you want the groups to be based on?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.  The current query just gets the individual transactions.  The SELECT shows 4 columns I was using.  I'd really like a table with my transaction groups on the left, the Count for each tranaction group in one column and the average transaction for that group in the next column.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Which fields would constitute a transaction group?

Comment: it would be useful to post a 'mockup' of what are you getting now and what are you expecting to get

Comment: The field that I would like to group on is a count of the balance change.  Each time a transaction happens, it changes the balance.  So for an individual, if they had a total of one transaction, I would like them in the group for 1-2 transactions.  If they had 3 transactions, they would go into the 3-4 transaction group.  But I need to create these groups.  I tried using the CASE command but was apparently making other errors because I hadn't properly used the GROUP BY command.  I'm not fluent in SQL.

Comment: Don't know how to make a table that will look right, but the transaction group will be in one column, the count for that group in the next column and the average transaction in the third column.

Comment: First try to get an SQL that returns sum and average count of transactions. That you'll get using group by and removing distinct. Then use that as a derived table and make a case -clause for the groups using the result of the sum column. I assume the grouping is more complex than just groups of 2 (that you could handle by dividing the number with 2)

Comment: throw input sample data and output sample data.

Comment: Thanks JamesZ.  I will give that a try.  However, I used the DISTINCT to get rid of some duplicate tuples.  Will these duplicates be an issue when I lose the DISTINCT and then group?  I haven't worked with derived tables but will read about it. KumarHarsh, I don't know what you mean by throw input sample data.

Comment: JamesZ-- I read about derived tables and did what you suggested with some success.  However, when I took out the DISTINCT from my original query to group on count and avg of balance change, the duplicates were reintroduced into the data.  Is there any way I can avoid this problem?